# Testing every occurrence of a XML node-set, not just the first

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to filter a list of courses based on which region they are offered in. But at the moment, it is only matching the first location in the list.

Code is:

```
<xsl:param name="r" />

<xsl:variable name="RegionList">
  <Region>
    <RegionID>EAST</RegionID>
    <RegionName>Eastern Region</RegionName>
    <Campuses>ABC, XYZ, PQR, WTF</Campuses>
  </Region>

[...]

</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="CourseItem">

  <xsl:for-each select="//CampusItem">
    <xsl:if test="((normalize-space($r) = '') or contains(msxsl:node-set($RegionList)/Region[RegionID=$r]/Campuses, .//OrganisationID))">

      <xsl:value-of select="CourseID"/>

    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

`$r` is the region being searched for. If left blank it should return all regions.

`$RegionList/Region[]/Campuses` is a comma-separated list of campus codes belonging to the specified region.

`OrganisationID` is the campus field in the XML.

XML sample:

```
 <CourseItem>
   <CourseID>C001</CourseID>
   [...]
   <Campus>
     <CampusItem>
       <OrganisationID>OMG</OrganisationID>
       [...]
     </CampusItem>
     <CampusItem>
       <OrganisationID>ABC</OrganisationID>
       [...]
     </CampusItem>
     <CampusItem>
       <OrganisationID>XYZ</OrganisationID>
       [...]
     </CampusItem>
   </Campus>
 </CourseItem>

 <CourseItem>
   <CourseID>C002</CourseID>
   [...]
   <Campus>
     <CampusItem>
       <OrganisationID>ZZZ</OrganisationID>
       [...]
     </CampusItem>
     <CampusItem>
       <OrganisationID>YYY</OrganisationID>
       [...]
     </CampusItem>
     <CampusItem>
       <OrganisationID>AAA</OrganisationID>
       [...]
     </CampusItem>
   </Campus>
 </CourseItem>

 <CourseItem>
   <CourseID>C003</CourseID>
   [...]
   <Campus>
     <CampusItem>
       <OrganisationID>BBB</OrganisationID>
       [...]
     </CampusItem>
     <CampusItem>
       <OrganisationID>WTF</OrganisationID>
       [...]
     </CampusItem>
     <CampusItem>
       <OrganisationID>CCC</OrganisationID>
       [...]
     </CampusItem>
   </Campus>
 </CourseItem>
```

So in the case of `C001`, the test is only checking against the first `OrganisationID`, and marks it as not appearing in Eastern Region, even though the next 2 campuses are. It should be finding *any* that match.

Desired output:

```
 C001
 C003
```

Comment: Could you not change the lookup list to proper XML (a node for each campus)? That would make the solution both simpler and more robust.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I could. Do you want to submit an answer that shows what to do with the `<xsl:if>` if the lookup is in that form?

Comment: Could you also add your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following **test input**:

```
<CourseItems>
    <CourseItem>
        <CourseID>C001</CourseID>
        <Campus>
            <CampusItem>
                <OrganisationID>XYZ</OrganisationID>
            </CampusItem>
            <CampusItem>
                <OrganisationID>DEF</OrganisationID>
            </CampusItem>
            <CampusItem>
                <OrganisationID>NOT</OrganisationID>
            </CampusItem>
        </Campus>
    </CourseItem>
    <CourseItem>
        <CourseID>C002</CourseID>
        <Campus>
            <CampusItem>
                <OrganisationID>PLO</OrganisationID>
            </CampusItem>
            <CampusItem>
                <OrganisationID>WWW</OrganisationID>
            </CampusItem>
        </Campus>
    </CourseItem>
    <CourseItem>
        <CourseID>C003</CourseID>
        <Campus>
            <CampusItem>
                <OrganisationID>DNA</OrganisationID>
            </CampusItem>
            <CampusItem>
                <OrganisationID>GHI</OrganisationID>
            </CampusItem>
        </Campus>
    </CourseItem>
</CourseItems>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:param name="region" select="'EAST'"/>

<xsl:variable name="campuses">
    <region id="EAST">
        <campus>ABC</campus>
        <campus>DEF</campus>
        <campus>GHI</campus>
    </region>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="CourseItems/CourseItem[Campus/CampusItem/OrganisationID=exsl:node-set($campuses)/region[@id=$region]/campus]">
            <xsl:value-of select="CourseID"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
C001
C003
```

Comment: AFAIK, MS have their own node-set() function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz88kef0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Nevermind... renaming from your examples back to my data, and I mixed the cases. It works now.

Comment: @michael.hor257k They do, but MSXSL also supports `exsl:node-set()`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide your complete XSLT, so I'm not sure if this approach is working for you. Also note that I didn't use the `msxsl` namespace, but you could adjust it for your settings. Following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat"
 omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="r" select="'EAST'"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CourseItem">
    <xsl:param name="r" />
    <xsl:variable name="RegionList">
      <Region>
        <RegionID>EAST</RegionID>
        <RegionName>Eastern Region</RegionName>
        <Campuses>ABC, XYZ, PQR, WTF</Campuses>
      </Region>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="Campus/CampusItem">
      <xsl:if test="((normalize-space($r) = '') or
    contains($RegionList/Region[RegionID=$r]/Campuses,
    OrganisationID))">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to the example input XML

```
<CourseItem>
  <CourseID>C001</CourseID>
  <Campus>
     <CampusItem>
       <OrganisationID>OMG</OrganisationID>
     </CampusItem>
     <CampusItem>
       <OrganisationID>ABC</OrganisationID>
     </CampusItem>
     <CampusItem>
       <OrganisationID>XYZ</OrganisationID>
     </CampusItem>
  </Campus>
</CourseItem>
```

produces the output

```
<CampusItem>
  <OrganisationID>ABC</OrganisationID>
</CampusItem>
<CampusItem>
  <OrganisationID>XYZ</OrganisationID>
</CampusItem>
```

As the full XSLT is not in the question, maybe just the

```
<xsl:for-each select="Campus/CampusItem">
...
```

is missing.

Comment: The content I want returned is in the `<CourseItem>` not the `<CampusItem>`. There are several courses, and I want just the ones taught at campuses in the selected region returned.